# HFST, python setup

Tags: macos, python-2.7, installation, python-bindings, hfst

I am building a morphological parser with [hfst](https://kitwiki.csc.fi/twiki/bin/view/KitWiki/HfstOverviewAndQuickStart?skin=clean.nat%2ceditdefault%2c%20pattern#Downloads), but am running into problems with installation.
I have successfully downloaded the hfst package, and it is present in the site-packages directory of my python framework. I can import it in python without a problem.
However, when I try to run some of the commands from the quickstart page, I get syntax errors:

```
>>> import hfst
>>> hfst-lexc -v -f foma finntreebank.lexc -o finntreebank.inverted.hfst
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    hfst-lexc -v -f foma finntreebank.lexc -o finntreebank.inverted.hfst
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is the problem that I need to install foma? Or is the interface between the C++ and python not working? It's been difficult to figure this out with the documentation.

Is there a resource for guidance on how to install and use C++ libraries in python?

Answer (score 1):

`hfst-lexc -v -f foma finntreebank.lexc -o finntreebank.inverted.hfst` is a command that you can run in a Unix shell / command line. It is not Python code.

If you're on Ubuntu or Mac, you can [open the Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) and `cd` to the directory of that file and run the command there.

See https://hfst.github.io/python/3.12.1/QuickStart.html for some examples of how to use HFST from Python. I don't know if a `lexc` command is available from the Python API, but it would probably be simplest to just run that example from the command line. You can still use the resulting `.hfst` file from Python to do lookups and such.